# Is there anyway to load TIFF image using Intel IPP?

Tags: tiff, libtiff, intel-ipp

I am using VS2008, on windows 7 32/64 bit.

I am trying to process a tiff image using IPP. I did some search, but have not found any possibility for Intel IPP to load tiff image. So I use libtiff to load tiff image. But the problem is, the datatype of the image is libtiff related, such as TIFFRGBAImage. These formats seems not acceptable to Intel IPP.

So, how do I process tiff image with Intel IPP? Or is there anyway to let Intel IPP accept datat type like TIFFRGBAImage? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I do not think so. But you can load the tiff file using libTIFF in to buffer, then process the buffer with IPP functions.